# Formatting a Date from a SharePoint List using Javascript and Momentjs

Tags: javascript, moment

I'm querying a SharePoint list using a JavaScript file and returning the results to a HTML page. All the results are coming back fine, but the results from the date column 'DeviceAvailableFrom' is coming back as NaN (aka Not a Number).

I'm using the Moment.js library but I'm new to it so don't know wuite how to format the var line. I want the date to come out DD-MM-YY. The current code which is returning the NaN is:

```
 var LifeCycleStart = new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom);
```

How would I work the Moment formatting in to get the desired results?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If `DeviceAvailableFrom` has the right values but in the wrong format, you can wrap it with moment by passing `var wrapper = moment(LifeCycleStart);` on the next line.

Comment: So it would be:
    var LifeCycleStart = new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom); 
    var wrapper = moment(LifeCycleStart); 

where would the formatting go?

Comment: Added the complete js below as an answer.

Comment: First check your data and list all those dates in F12 with ``console.log( typeof item.DeviceAvailableFrom , item.DeviceAvailableFrom )`` to check what you get from SP

Comment: Oddly enough when I put the console.log line in it knocks out the rest of the results

Answer (score 2):

If `DeviceAvailableFrom` has the right values but in the wrong format, you can wrap & format it with moment on the next line.

```
var LifeCycleStart = new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom);
var wrapper = moment(wrapper).format("DD-MM-YY");
```

I haven't tested the script.

Edit: Ty Danny '365CSI' Engelman for pointing out the double-conversion.

Comment: You are then doing the Moment conversion twice..

Comment: Thanks. If I add that code it knows the rest of he results out. 

However, if I add: var LifeCycleStart=new Date();
            LifeCycleStart.toString('dddd,MMM,yyyy');

It brings up todays date and time, so I need to find a way to parse in the results from the DeviceAvailableFrom column...

Comment: 'var LifeCycleStart = new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom);
var wrapper = moment(wrapper).format("DD-MM-YY");'

Thanks. That code knocks out he rest of the results.

Answer (score 1):

If the date is blank it is not a Number

```
var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
if (LifeCycleStart) LifeCycleStart=new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom);
```

And you don't need MomentJS

SharePoint adds a `String.format` function
so you can use:

```
String.format('{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}',new Date('2015-10-07T20:39:54Z'));
```

Note: String.format is defined in `msajaxbundle.js`, loaded even before most of the JavaScript files so safe to use without SOD requirements or anything.
It was modelled after the C# and VB implementations, 
so [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Format_Params) applies
(*for the major part; it does not do the alignment stuff as that makes no sense in HTML*)

```
String.format("{0:i}",new Date());  outputs: Wed Oct 07 2015 20:39:54 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)
String.format("{0:F}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39:54
String.format("{0:f}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015 20:39
String.format("{0:D}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday, 07 October 2015
String.format("{0:s}",new Date());  outputs: 2015-10-07T20:39:54
String.format("{0:d}",new Date());  outputs: 10/07/2015
String.format("{0:dd}",new Date());  outputs: 07
String.format("{0:ddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wed
String.format("{0:dddd}",new Date());  outputs: Wednesday
String.format("{0:m}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:M}",new Date());  outputs: October 07
String.format("{0:MM}",new Date());  outputs: 10
String.format("{0:MMM}",new Date());  outputs: Oct
String.format("{0:MMMM}",new Date());  outputs: October
String.format("{0:Y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:y}",new Date());  outputs: 2015 October
String.format("{0:yy}",new Date());  outputs: 15
String.format("{0:yyyy}",new Date());  outputs: 2015
String.format("{0:gg}",new Date());  outputs: A.D.
String.format("{0:T}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39:54
String.format("{0:t}",new Date());  outputs: 20:39
String.format("{0:HH}",new Date());  outputs: 20
String.format("{0:mm}",new Date());  outputs: 39
String.format("{0:ss}",new Date());  outputs: 54
```

#### It does more then just Dates:

[MSDN String.format() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

J5 iJS string format top20 iDate

Comment: Cheers, I've added:

   var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
if (LifeCycleStart) LifeCycleStart=new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom); 
     String.format('{0:dd}-{0:MM}-{0:yyyy}',new Date('2015-10-07T20:39:54Z'));

and I'm getting 'null' when there isn't a date and NaN when there is a date?